# How to store an array of ones and zeros in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I the average is greater than 0 then put 100 ones, else put 100 zeros, but I cant get it to work.

```
zero = zeros(1,100);
one = ones(1, 100);
demodulation = [zero zero zero zero zero zero zero zero];

for i=1:1:8;
 if (average > 0)
        demodulation(i) =  ones(1,100);
    else
        demodulation(i) = zeros(1,1);
    end
```

But I get this error in MATLAB:
http://prntscr.com/2ie6k1

```
In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in roman_test (line 50)
        demodulation(i) = ones(1,100)
```

Comment: demodulation can be two dimensional array as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that error, I'm guessing `i` is a single index. You can't store a 1x100 vector in a single element of another vector - you need to specify 100 elements of the destination vector to store it.

Assuming `i` is between 1 and 8, what you want to do is:

```
demodulation((1:100) + (i-1)*100) = ones(1,100);
```

and similarly for the zero case, where you're currently just assigning a single `0`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i=0:100:800, you need something more like

```
   demodulation(i+1:i+100) = 1;
```

If  `i=1:8`, then you need:

```
   demodulation(1+(i-1)*100:i*100) = 1;
```

and conversely for the other case.

Note that, as `average` does not seem to depend on `i`,   you could simply write

```
zero = zeros(1,100);
one = ones(1, 100);
demodulation = [zero zero zero zero zero zero zero zero] + average>0;
```

Or you could

```
if average>0
    demodulation = ones(1,800)
else
    demodulation = zeros(1,800)
```

which minimizes memory allocation and setup.

Comment: what is the value of `i` ?

Comment: It does not depend on i, and it works, so both answers are correct